# Why does using json_decode on this JSON string result in a null value

Tags: php, json, jsondecoder

```
"op=add&item={"firstName":"test","lastName":"test","email":"test%40test.com","password":"test"}"
```

I'm passing the JSON body above to my PHP backend and when trying to use json_decode on it, it results in null. I've used json_last_error() and it states there is a syntax issue. Using jsonlint.com, it gives me this error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
"op=add&item={"firstName ":"test "
---------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'
```

I've tried troubleshooting this error but haven't been able to get a successful response. Can someone describe what the issue could be?

Comment: You are doing a `json_decode()` on WHAT? Code is really useful as we are all coders. The only JSON part of that string is the `{"firstName":"test","lastName":"test","email":"test%40test.com","password":"test"}` bit, which explains the error

Answer (score 0):

For `json_decode()` to work, it requires a string.
Looking at you syntax, it seems the outer quotes aren't correct.

Yours:

```
"op=add&item={"firstName":"test","lastName":"test","email":"test%40test.com","password":"test"}"
```

As they should be:

```
'op=add&item={"firstName":"test","lastName":"test","email":"test%40test.com","password":"test"}'
```

If you use single quotes, it's a correct string. Which can be decoded.

Answer (score 0):

Your "body" isn't a JSON string, only the **item** parameter content looks like one. Take that content and pass to the function **json_decode**.

Example:

```
json_decode($_GET['item']);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a useful function to debug json issues

```
    function json_validate($string){
    // decode the JSON data
    $result = json_decode($string);

    // switch and check possible JSON errors
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            $error = ''; // JSON is valid // No error has occurred
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            $error = 'The maximum stack depth has been exceeded.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            $error = 'Invalid or malformed JSON.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            $error = 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            $error = 'Syntax error, malformed JSON.';
            break;
        // PHP >= 5.3.3
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            $error = 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.';
            break;
        // PHP >= 5.5.0
        case JSON_ERROR_RECURSION:
            $error = 'One or more recursive references in the value to be encoded.';
            break;
        // PHP >= 5.5.0
        case JSON_ERROR_INF_OR_NAN:
            $error = 'One or more NAN or INF values in the value to be encoded.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE:
            $error = 'A value of a type that cannot be encoded was given.';
            break;
        default:
            $error = 'Unknown JSON error occured.';
            break;
    }

    if ($error !== '') {
        // throw the Exception or exit // or whatever :)
        exit($error);
    }

    // everything is OK
    return $result;
}
```